# iterator with vector pointer

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I created a vector of pointers

```
vector<Person*> *personVec = new vector<Person*>();
```

Person contains:

```
getName();
getAge();
```

If I try to use the iterator it doesn't work.. Here is how I use it:

```
    vector<Person>::iterator it;
    for(it = personVec->begin() ;
        it != personVec->end() ;
        ++it)
    {
        cout << it->getName() << endl;
    }
```

I tried `vector<Person*>::iterator it;` but no luck with that either.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't get a `vector<Person>::iterator` from a `vector<Person*>`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iterator needs to be the same type as the container:

```
vector<Person>::iterator it;
```

should be:

```
vector<Person*>::iterator it;
```

Comment: +1, also the `it->getName()` should become `(*it)->getName()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 vector<Person*> *personVec = new vector<Person*>();
```

this is a pointer to a vector of person pointers

```
vector<Person>::iterator it;
for(it = personVec->begin() ; it != personVec->end() ; ++it)
{
    cout << it->getName() << endl;
}
```

your iter is declare incorrectly you need an iter to a vector of person pointers

you have an iter to a vector of person s

```
vector<Person*>::iterator it;
for(it = personVec->begin() ; it != personVec->end() ; ++it)
{
    cout << (*it)->getName() << endl;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/

and

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/begin/